# Better way to overload a method from two different classes in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have two parent classes I cannot redefine (say, `A` and `B`), with methods I need to overload using the exact same way (so as to obtain, say, `BetterA` and `BetterB`).
I could duplicate the code for both classes, but I am not satisfied with that.
In Python 3.6, I thought I can get rid of this using multi inheritance and a provider class.
This is what I obtained so far:

```
# here are the initial classes I cannot edit
class A:
    def __init__(self, a=0):
        self.a = a

class B:
    def __init__(self, b=0):
        self.b = b

# here is the provider class
class Provider:
    def __init__(self, c, *args, **kwargs):
        self.c = c

        # more code here

        self.init_child(*args, **kwargs)

# here are the new classes
class BetterA(Provider, A):
    def init_child(self, *args, **kwargs):
        A.__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class BetterB(Provider, B):
    def init_child(self, *args, **kwargs):
        B.__init__(*args, **kwargs)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = BetterA(8, a=10)
    b = BetterB(10, b=8)
```

This works, but it is not very graceful…
Especially, if I want to override more methods (always, in the same way), I have to recall them in `BetterA` and `BetterB`.

If there a better way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`super()` works with multiple inheritance:

```
# here is the provider class
class Provider:
    def __init__(self, c, *args, **kwargs):
        self.c = c

        # more code here

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

# here are the new classes
class BetterA(Provider, A):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class BetterB(Provider, B):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = BetterA(8, a=10)
    b = BetterB(10, b=8)
```

and you don’t need to redefine `Better*.__init__` if it’s not doing anything beyond calling the super method:

```
# here are the new classes
class BetterA(Provider, A):
    pass

class BetterB(Provider, B):
    pass
```

Another option you might prefer depending on whether you need to implement any more functionality in the `Better*` types is a function to create a class:

```
def provided(cls):
    class Provided(cls):
        def __init__(self, c, *args, **kwargs):
            self.c = c

            # more code here

            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    return Provided


BetterA = provided(A)
BetterB = provided(B)
```

Comment: Wow! I would say this is a "super" solution! But I'm wondering: which `init` the `super` at line 8 (first code block) is calling and how?

Comment: @Neraste: It’s calling `A.__init__` or `B.__init__` according to `BetterA.__mro__` or `BetterB.__mro__`.